# Insert taking less than 1 second to run, but it keeps looping in the same SPID

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm looking for a behaviour that I'm not sure how to explain.

Using `sp_whoisactive`, I can see an insert going on for hours:

[image: here]

But each time , it takes less than 1 second but it's still using the same SPID. there's pageio Latch on the wait status but, why is this query using the same SPID and don't let it go after each insert?  Does this mean that the application is using the same connection without closing it right?

This is also using a lot of version store. I'm trying to figure it out if there's a way to help.

[image: index is heavily used here for the insert.]

Comment: Looks even worse to me: the client is doing *single-row* inserts in a loop, yeah that's slow

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that the application is using the same connection
> without closing it right?

Not necessarily. It is common to see activity on the same SPID(s) from an application instance even when the app code closes the connection. Most apps use [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) (the default with ADO.NET) to avoid the cost of establishing a new network connection and authentication for every query.

When an application closes a connection with connection pooling, the connection is returned to the application connection pool for later reuse. The physical network connection remains open on the server and the inactive SPID will show as sleeping in SQL Server. You can see the sleeping SPIDs too with:

```
EXEC sp_whoisactive @show_sleeping_spids = 2;
```

The SPIDs from the same application instance are the active connections plus inactive (sleeping) pooled connections.